# How to get search results from each index

Tags: node.js, search, elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Search in Node Js to query multiple indexes, How do I get results from each of the index:

```
var esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({host: config.elasticsearch.host});

esClient.search({
    index: ["abc", "xyz"],
    type: ["abc", "xyz"],
    body: {
        query: {
            multi_match: {
                query: q,
                type: "cross_fields",
                analyzer: "ac_search_analyzer",
                operator: op,
                fields: ["a^4", "b^4", "c^2", "d", "e"]
            }
        }
    },
    _sourceInclude: ["a", "b", "c"],
    size: 10
}).then(function (resp) {
    //do something
}
```

Now I get all the 10 results only from `abc` and no results comes from `xyz`. What should I do to get say 5 results from `abc` and 5 from `xyz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-msearch) to query 5 results from each of the index in a single round trip.

Example:

```
client.msearch({
        body: [
            { _index: "abc", type: "abc"},
            {
                query : { 
                    multi_match: {
                        query: q,
                        type: "cross_fields",
                        analyzer: "ac_search_analyzer",
                        operator: op,
                        fields: ["a^4", "b^4", "c^2", "d", "e"]
                    }
                }, 
                size : 5,
                _source : ["a", "b", "c"]
            },
            { _index: "xyz", type: "xyz"},
            {
                query : { 
                    multi_match: {
                        query: q,
                        type: "cross_fields",
                        analyzer: "ac_search_analyzer",
                        operator: op,
                        fields: ["a^4", "b^4", "c^2", "d", "e"]
                    }
                }, 
                size : 5,
                _source : ["a", "b", "c"]
            }
        ],
}).then(function (resp) {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

**UPDATED EXAMPLE-2**

```
msearch_query ={
                query : { 
                    multi_match: {
                        query: q,
                        type: "cross_fields",
                        analyzer: "ac_search_analyzer",
                        operator: op,
                        fields: ["a^4", "b^4", "c^2", "d", "e"]
                    }
                }, 
                size : 5,
                _source : ["a", "b", "c"]
            };
client.msearch({
        body: [
            { _index: "test", type: "test"},
            msearch_query,
            { _index: "new", type: "new"},
            msearch_query
        ],
}).then(function (resp) {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Comment: So I have to write a search query for each index?
What can be better programmatic way to do it for multiple indexes?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "better programmatic way" ? If the query is different for each index there is no way around it but having to construct a query for index . If the query is the same you can always assign it to variable and reuse it as you construct the `msearch` query . Not sure if that is what your asking ? see updated example

Comment: @saurabh does this not answer the question ?